# Pandas PIVOT Dataframe and combine columns names by levels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df_dict = dict(
        key1 = [a,a,b,a,a,b,b,a,a,b,b],
        key2 = [A,B,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B],
        level = [leve1,leve1,leve1,leve2,leve2,leve2,leve2,level3,level3,level3,level3],
        var1 = [1,8,20,4,10,16,22,6,12,18,24]
        var2 = [2,9,21,5,11,17,23,7,13,19,25]
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

I want to pivot my table in order to have the var's columns per each level. The output that I expect would looks like this:

```
key 1 | key 2 | leve1_var1 | leve1_var2 | leve2_var1 | leve2_var2 | level3_var1 | level3_var2 |
______________________________________________________________________________________________|
a     | A     | 1          | 2          | 4          | 5          | 6           | 7           |
a     | B     | 8          | 9          | 10         | 11         | 12          | 13          |
b     | A     | 0          | 0          | 16         | 17         | 18          | 19          |
b     | B     | 20         | 21         | 22         | 23         | 24          | 25          |
```

I tried with

```
df.pivot_table(index=['key1','key2'],columns='level')
```

But it gives me first the variables and per each variable the levels, and I want to have all the variables for the same level together. Also, I have not been able to solve the problem of combining the labels of the level + '_'+ variable. Note that in the output zero is filled in the combinations that do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a little more processing.

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['key1','key2'],columns='level', fill_value=0)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
df1 = df1.sort_index(1).reset_index()

Out[41]:
  key1 key2  leve1_var1  leve1_var2  leve2_var1  leve2_var2  level3_var1  level3_var2
0    a    A           1           2           4           5            6            7
1    a    B           8           9          10          11           12           13
2    b    A           0           0          16          17           18           19
3    b    B          20          21          22          23           24           25
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['key1','key2','level']).unstack().fillna(0)
new_columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(1) + '_' + df2.columns.get_level_values(0)
df2 = df2.droplevel(0,axis=1)
df2.columns = new_columns
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```